# stripe=8191 on non-raid drive

Tags: filesystems, mount

I just noticed the following weirdness in the output of `mount` on my machine (Xubuntu 18.04):

```
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/Z2 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt/W type ext4 (rw,relatime,stripe=8191)
/dev/sdc1 on /mnt/X type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdd1 on /mnt/Y type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sde1 on /mnt/Z type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

That one drive (partition) with the "stripe=8191" has never been part of a RAID volume.  /etc/fstab for all drives has options set to "defaults".  I don't recall seeing the stripe option in there before, but I don't look at a mount listing all that often.

I googled up [one hit on the gentoo forum](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1061608-start-0.html) that suggests it can be safely removed with `tune2fs -E "" /dev/sde1`.  But as this data is critical (yes, it's backed up), I'm hesitant to mess with the filesystem.

Any ideas how that stripe got in there, whether it can be ignored, and/or how to remove it?

Answer (score 2):

The `stripe=` mount option is added automatically for ext4 created with the `stride=stride-size` and `stripe_width=stripe-width` options for `mkfs.ext4`. These options are designed to be used with RAID drives, but some older howtos recommend setting `stride` and `stripe_width` also for SSD to align the ext4 blocks to SSD erase block size. As far as I can tell this shouldn't be needed with TRIM/discard support, but it doesn't hurt and I would just ignore it.

Not sure if you added the options manually when creating ext4 on `/dev/sdb1` manually, it's also possible that the tool you used added these option automatically when it detected the device is an SSD.

Some reading if you are interested:

- [Theodore Tso: Aligning filesystems to an SSD’s erase block size](https://thunk.org/tytso/blog/2009/02/20/aligning-filesystems-to-an-ssds-erase-block-size/)
- [Magic soup: ext4 with SSD, stripes and strides.](https://thelastmaimou.wordpress.com/2013/05/04/magic-soup-ext4-with-ssd-stripes-and-strides/)
- [Gentoo Wiki: SSD: Configuring for erase block size](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSD#Formatting)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and the links.  To clarify:  the drive is a regular HDD, not SSD.  As to partitioning, I typically create an unformatted one with gparted so that the alignment is correct.  Then I create the filesystem manually with `mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -i 262144 /dev/sda1` so that I can specify those two options.

I did have an incident the other day where I was hot-swapping this drive back into the system, and the machine locked up.  On reboot, fsck fixed some errors - but on another drive (the home drive, which is an SSD), not the drive with the stripe=.  Not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: I think that even storage devices with TRIM/discard support do benefit from correctly aligned data access because any write crossing boundary between two erase blocks requires using two blocks instead of one. If you had really poor configuration, that could cut performance of writing small files in half. But it should be about performance tuning, not a data correctness setting.